# Multiple UIWebView in UIView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview

Anybody please give me some idea that how can i implement multiple UIWebView in UIView just like in BBC App.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

hello first create an object and place it on the correct spot then :

```
[self.view addSubview:YOUR OBECT];
```

here is an example that will help you (see under Adding a label programmatically)
http://chris-software.com/index.php/2009/04/29/creating-a-view-programmatically/

cheers endo

Comment: i think, memory has to suffer in this case, if i create 10 webview and add them on UIScrollView, it will increase the processing time. Is there any light way to do this. i saw this type of thing in every news iphone application but they run smoothly.